# Specify the bootstrapped node in MAAS?

Tags: maas

I am testing out MAAS in a demo environment of differently specified machines and would like the bootstrap node to be the smaller of the machines. Is there a way to specify the bootstrap node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current way to do this unfortunately, you need to wait for the constraints work to be finished.

[Edit: 2012-10-17]
The contraints work is now finished for 12.10.  You can specify cpu and memory requirements using juju.  See https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/reference-constraints

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your answer with more information  What is the constraints work?  where can we review the status of this work etc?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I eventually did this by starting fresh and only adding the bootstrap node to the MAAS and then bootstrapping. But I ended up with plenty of other issues which are likely due to the current maturity level of Juju / MAAS.